# How to get the frames in Android?

Tags: android, video, media

I'm trying to take all the images frames from video file for that I'm using MediaMetaDataReteriver to get that images and store it in SDCard with the help arraylist Bitmap but I'm not interested in using FFMPEG.

Actually what I need was to get images of different frames but it repeats the same first frames for each time the loop runs.

To fix this issues I'd searched in the internet lot and fixed but nothing helped me it remains the same.

If some one have any idea about this or any other alternative methods to fix this issues so please help me guys.

Here is my full code below:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File videoFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Movies/MEMO.mp4");

        Uri videoFileUri=Uri.parse(videoFile.toString());

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        ArrayList<Bitmap> rev=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


        //Create a new Media Player
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), videoFileUri);
        int millis = mp.getDuration();
        for(int i=0;i<millis;i+=100){
           Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
           rev.add(bitmap);

          try {
              saveFrames(rev);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }



    public void saveFrames(ArrayList<Bitmap> saveBitmapList) throws IOException{

        String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File saveFolder = new File(folder + "/Movies/new /");
        if(!saveFolder.exists()){
           saveFolder.mkdirs();
        }


        int i=1;
        for (Bitmap b : saveBitmapList){
           ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

            File f = new File(saveFolder,("frame"+i+".jpg"));

            f.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

               fo.flush();
               fo.close();

            i++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Another approach: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest

Comment: I have tried but it remains the same can you help me Sir.

Comment: Sir can you please help me by your full sample code for this process

Answer (score 0):

I think the time is in microsceconds. The `US` postfix on the argument denoting that.

So you need to multiply by 1,000,000 and divide by the frame rate. So if the frame rate is 30fps:

```
long timeUS = 1000000 * i / 30;
```

So in your code, this would take the first 100 frames:

```
int total_frames = 100;
for(int f = 0; f < total_frames; f++){
    long timeUS = 1000000 * f / 30;
    Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(timeUS, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

Comment: Sir i'm sorry to say you this i'd tried with the above loop condition which is give by you to get all different frames but it remains the same no change i can't find were it goes wrong should any thing add in AndroidManifest

Comment: The trouble with `getFrameAtTime()` is that it's really meant for grabbing thumbnails.  It's a bit slow and awkward for grabbing lots of frames.  Still, it shouldn't fail as described... the code in the answer looks like it should fix the issue.

Comment: Actually my video file duration is 127040(2:07sec) i divided my total frames as(32) i can view all my 32 frames as a same first frame by saving it in SDCard i don't know where it's goes wrong even in my Logcat there is no error message.